# Phone Texting Software

Tags: sms, mms

Does anyone know of any software that helps somebody manage a large inflow and outflow of phone texts?  Google voice's standard web application is great, but I'm looking for something more.  The feature I would kill for is the ability to send **conditional texting**.  For example, it would be awesome to set up a text that would automatically send if somebody didn't respond within a certain time frame.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up and manage multiple numbers on [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/). You can also write scripts for them, I'm sure if you were clever enough you could meet all your needs.

For instance all of your texts can goto a database, where a server is running a script. It can check timestamps and send out texts. You can then sort and manage your texts however you see fit, once you have the raw data.

Comment: Do you know of any Twilio GUI's out there that can help someone with limited programming experience take advantage of their api?

Comment: I do not, find me on google for private assistance with those specifics and good luxk